# How can I detect if a StorageFile was renamed or deleted in a UWP app?

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, storagefile

For a Windows Store app: how can I detect if a `StorageFile` was renamed or deleted outside of my application while it is open in my app?

I have a Windows 10 UWP app running on the desktop. The app lets the user open and edit documents.

Things I've tried:

- **Checking DateModified**:

  - I tried checking `storageFile.GetBasicPropertiesAsync().DateModified`, but even it I delete the file and empty the trash, the call returns successfully with the (old) `DateModified`. (I assume it uses an in-memory version and does not check the file on disk)
- **Re-Open the StorageFile**:

  - I then tried to "re-open" the file using `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(file.Path)`. This correctly threw a `FileNotFoundException` the first time.
  - However, later this failed with an `Unauthorized access/permission denied` exception. It kind of makes sense, because I need the user to pick the file in a FileOpenPicker to have my app get permission to use it.
- **Monitor the parent folder:**

  - Did not get far with this one. I tried to use `StorageFolder.CreateFileQuery()`, but I can't access the parent folder form the StorageFile instance (again, it makes sense, because my app does not have permission to access the parent folder)

Answer (score 1):

Found a nice and short way to check if file was deleted:

```
public async bool StorageFileExists(StorageFile file)
{
  try
  {
    var stream = await StorageFile.OpenReadAsync();
    stream.Dispose();
    return true;
  }
  catch (FileNotFoundException e)
  {
    return false;
  } //Other exceptions are not caught on purpose and should propagate
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even in a UWP App you can use `System.IO.File.Exists(String)`. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx